# charAt(0) throws a string out of bounds exception

Tags: java

So my teacher wants me to write program where I have to read through a txt file and assign each line as a string to a TreeMap in alphabetic order. I tried to use Scanner to read through the file and I'm trying to get the first letter of each line by using the charAt(0) method but every time I run it, it returns an error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0" So if anyone can point out the mistakes I made in the program I would really appreciate it.

[image: Here is a picture of the text file that I am trying to read]

```
 TreeMap<Integer, String> list= new TreeMap<Integer, String>(); 
  Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in); 
  System.out.println("Enter file name");
  String filename= scan.nextLine();

  try{ 
   scan= new Scanner (Paths.get(filename)); 
   }
  catch (IOException ioException)
  {
  System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
  System.exit(1);
  }

  try
  {
   while(scan.hasNextLine())
   {
    String line= scan.nextLine(); 
    char ch1 = line.charAt(0);
    int key=(int) ch1; 
    list.put(key, line);  
   }
  }
 catch (IllegalStateException stateException)
 {
  System.err.println("Error reading from file. Terminating.");
  System.exit(1);
 }
```

Comment: That means the string you're trying to get the first character of is empty. You'll need to check for that prior to trying to get the character.

Comment: Your file has a newline in it.

Comment: You have an empty line in the input data.

Comment: Time to learn how to step through your code line by line in the IDE debugger.

Comment: Scanner doesn't include the newline, correct?

Comment: Looks like a trailing newline.

Comment: I added a picture of the file that I inputted, hope that helps

Comment: I switched it to next() instead of nextLine and combined it with a length check it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a length check before reading the 1st character:

```
if(line.length() > 0) {
    char ch1 = line.charAt(0);
    int key = (int)ch1; 
    list.put(key, line); 
}
```

Your file likely has a trailing newline, which `Scanner` strips off, leaving you with an empty string.

Comment: It's actually probably the fact that there's a trailing newline.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Much appreciated.